# Samba or smbclient can not connect to windows local disk or share like c$, d$

Tags: linux, share, samba

i am having a trouble to connect to a windows disk c or d from linux, but i can do this from windows with no problem like issuing 

`//192.168.1.100/C$`.
From linux  i do this 

 `#smbclient  '//192.168.1.100/C$' -U myuser`
and get error like **tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED**
but i can connect to other shares like

 `#smbclient  '//192.168.1.100/test_share' -U myuser`

 Could anyone tell me why i can't connect via linux to windows partitions

```
smbclient -L  '//192.168.1.100/ 




   Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------          
    ADMIN$          Disk      Remote Admin
    C$              Disk      Default share
    test_share Disk      
    distr           Disk      
    IPC$            IPC       Remote IPC
    Users           Disk
```

Comment: And you can mount the admin share with "myuser" from another windows machine? AFAIK the "$" admin shares can only be mounted by a (local?) Administrator user.

Comment: Are you using a windows domain, or just a workgroup? Maybe windows used the domain user `myuser` to connect, but from linux, if you don't specify the domain, the local user is selected. If yes, try `-U domain/myuser`.

Comment: i use workgroup WORKGROUP

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.nooblet.org/blog/2011/access-windows-7-admin-shares-from-linux/, the following registry setting is required on the Windows machine:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy"=dword:00000001
```